# Exibir produtos randômicamente de acordo com a categoria

Tags: php, magento

Estou tentando alterar a exibição dos produtos para random quando apenas quando a categoria for filha da principal fiz o seguinte codigo:

```
$id = 2;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();
$categoria = $_productCollection->getCategoryIds();
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid){
     $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
    if($_category->getIsActive() and $categoria = $_category ){
     $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    }
}
```

Tem um monte de erro :( quem poder ajudar ai agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui!

```
$current_id=  Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getId();/Pega a id do pai da categoria selecionada */

$current_id2=  Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();//pega a id da categoria selecionada

$catPrincipal = 2;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catPrincipal);/* Carrega categoria pelo id */
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();/*Retorna os Ids separados por virgula*/
$x = 0;
$catFilhas = array();/* Array com as filhas*/
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid){
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()){
        $catFilhas[$x] = $_category->getId();
    }
    $x++;
}

if($current_id == $catPrincipal){// Checa se a categoria é filha da categoria principal
    $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($current_id2))
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->joinField(
            'is_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'is_in_stock',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 1))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
        ->setPageSize(8);
        $_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
}else{
    foreach($catFilhas as $values){
        if($current_id == $values){//Checa se é uma subcategoria das categorias filhas da principal
            $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($current_id2))
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->joinField(
                'is_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'is_in_stock',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 1))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->setPageSize(8);
            $_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
            break;
        }
    }
        if(!isset($_productCollection)){// Se não cair em nenhuma das duas ultimas condições
            $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); 
        }
}

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode utilizar algo assim:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="home.catalog.product.featured" category_id="60" columnCount="2" num_products="4" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}
```

Vou tentar explicar um pouco mais:

Aqui carregamos o tipo de catalogo ramdom:

```
type="catalog/product_list_random"
```

Categoria a ser filtrada:

```
category_id="60"
```

Quantidade de colunas, não é necessário:

```
columnCount="2"
```

Quantidade de produtos a serem listados:

```
num_products="4"
```

Modelo de template a ser utilizado para exibição:

```
template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"
```

No arquivo de list você precisa adicionar o filtro de categoria específico conforme abaixo:

```
<?php

$categoryid = 12;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Muito [**peixe**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1968/ensinar-a-pescar-ou-dar-o-peixe) nas suas últimas respostas, meu caro Otto :( . . .  E se eu quisesse saber por que seu código resolve o problema?

Comment: Mestre @brasofilo tentei explicar um pouco melhor o funcionamento, grato pela crítica

Comment: cara já tentei assim a questão é que essa verificação tem que ser feita dentro do arquivo list.phtml

Comment: atualizei a resposta espero que lhe ajude

Comment: vou testar aqui agradeço a atenção.

Comment: atualizei ai a pergunta cara espero que agora entenda exatamente o que eu estou tentando fazer.